# Bind color to a specific xvalue in an asp.net chart using xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, charts, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created an ASPx Pie Chart and am struggling a bit with getting the colors right. Important to note is that I do not have control over the back-end code (3rd party) at all and am therefore limited to XML modifications only (Microsoft Dynamics CRM).

The problem is that I want to use colours indicating a certain status of the records returned (e.g. number of days a book is overdue in the library). I want to have a siutation like this:

0-5 days late (= code 0) ----> green

5-10 days late (= code 1) ----> yellow

10-15 days late (= code 2) ----> orange

```
>15 days late (= code 3) ----> red
```

The data I am receiving from the server is for example:

Code (days late)        Count (books)
0                          4
2                          5
3                          14

This works when I use the **PaletteCustomColors** attribute and specify the colours like this:

```
<Chart Palette="None" PaletteCustomColors="149,189,66; 255,255,0; 255,136,35; 197,56,52; 117,82,160; 55,118,193; 168,203,104; 142,116,178; 93,186,215; 255,155,83">
  <Series>
    <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieDrawingStyle=Default" ChartType="pie">
      <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
    </Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea>
      <Area3DStyle Enable3D="true" />
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Legends>
    <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
  </Legends>
  <Titles>
    <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
  </Titles>
</Chart>
```

**However,** this does not work when a certain code is not present. In this case the colors will be:

Code 0 -> green,
Code 2 -> yellow,
Code 3 -> organge

So since no Code 1 result was returned (as the count for this code is 0 no result is returned from the app), code 2 takes the first remaining color, code 3 taks the color after that, ... **Which is not what I want, I want the colors to be bound to their Code property.**

I have tried using DataPoints for this (see code below), but to no avail... Does anyone have any decent solution?

```
    <Chart>
  <Series>
    <Series ShadowOffset="0" IsValueShownAsLabel="True" Font="{0}, 9.5px" LabelForeColor="59, 59, 59" CustomProperties="PieLabelStyle=Inside, PieDrawingStyle=Default" ChartType="pie">
      <SmartLabelStyle Enabled="True" />
      <Points>
        <DataPoint XValue="0" Color="Green" />
        <DataPoint XValue="1" Color="Yellow" />
        <DataPoint XValue="2" Color="Orange" />
        <DataPoint XValue="3" Color="Red" />
        <DataPoint XValue="4" Color="Purple" />
    </Points>
    </Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <ChartArea>
      <Area3DStyle Enable3D="true" />
    </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
  <Legends>
    <Legend Alignment="Center" LegendStyle="Table" Docking="right" IsEquallySpacedItems="True" Font="{0}, 11px" ShadowColor="0, 0, 0, 0" ForeColor="59, 59, 59" />
  </Legends>
  <Titles>
    <Title Alignment="TopLeft" DockingOffset="-3" Font="{0}, 13px" ForeColor="0, 0, 0"></Title>
  </Titles>
</Chart>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to include some dummy records in your View, and then change your chart xml to not include them when aggregating the data.
You can see a full example of the method here http://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/specify-exact-colors-for-each-priority-in-the-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-case-chart/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a proxy service in the middle?

Instead of this: 
Code (days late) Count (books) 0 4 2 5 3 14

Your service would inject the zero valued items:
Code (days late) Count (books) 0 4 **1 0** 2 5 3 14